# How to keep OS specific configuration for eslint

Tags: macos, atom-editor, eslint

I currently work in a team which uses atom as the editor of choice but split between windows and OSX. Our .eslintrc.js reports the linebreak-style as an issue on windows(Expect line ending to be LF but found CRLF) but works fine on OSX.
Is there a way to specify to eslint that only check this rule while on OSX

Comment: Just get the text editors to always save as LF.

Comment: Many editors will honour an [`.editorconfig` file](http://editorconfig.org/). Specify `end_of_line = lf` within it and be done with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of having this rule enabled is to unify the line endings along all the OS and editors. Probably your coworkers that are using Windows have not configured `LF` (OSX, Linux) line endings in their editors, and have instead `CRLF` (Windows). This is normally configurable in most editors.

If you want to allow different line endings on Windows, I think the best option is to configure your version control to unify it on commit, like indicated in [this post](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#example), i.e. `text eol=lf` in your project's `.gitattributes`.

Otherwise, as per the comments, a good solution is to create a `end_of_line = lf` in a [.editorconfig file](http://editorconfig.org/).